# Admin interface editable Django app settings

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, settings, usability

Is there a good way provide user configurable app settings in Django admin?

Basically I would like to have a nice forms where site owner can easily edit such one off information as his contact information, front page text content, etc. Sort of like a normal admin interface of a model, but limited to only one undeletable item in the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third-party project [django-dbsettings](http://code.google.com/p/django-values/) is ideal for this.

Comment: Looks like it is the only one for it :)

Answer (score 17):

I think [django constance](https://github.com/comoga/django-constance) is the way to go. Alive and compatible with django 1.4.

Comment: Its 2016 and this project seems like the most active.

Comment: It's 2023 and [django-constance](https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance) is still alive the most active of all the projects listed. Most recent version bump: v3.1.0 (2023/08/21)

Answer (score 3):

I looked at dbsettings and liked some of what I saw, but I really wanted a more centralized, organized system. So I built [django-appsettings](http://github.com/jabapyth/django-appsettings). Enjoy :)

Comment: yeah, those [past two years](http://jaredforsyth.com/mission) I've been in Germany for my church ;) But now I'm back, and am slowly getting my many projects back up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

Found this: [django-livesettings](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings)